# relation between direct and indirect BFGS algorithm

Tags: calculus, algorithms

I am trying to verfiry the calculation of $B^{-1}_{k+1}$ from the [Wikipage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm#Algorithm). I tried using Sherman–Morrison formula twice:
$$\left(\underbrace{B-\frac{1}{s^tBs}Bss^tB}_{=:A}+\frac{1}{s^ty}yy^t\right)^{-1}=A^{-1}+\frac{A^{-1}yy^tA^{-1}}{s^ty+y^tA^{-1}y}$$
Now, if I try to use Sherman–Morrison formula for the second time to calculate $A^{-1}$. I find that
$$A^{-1}=B^{-1}-\frac{B^{-1}Bss^tBB^{-1}}{s^tBs-s^tBB^{-1}Bs}$$ the denominator is zero! What did I miss? Where is my mistake?